# Django Variations not displayed

Tags: python, django, product-variations

In order to list my variations_value i render data into context but when i pass the object to the frontend it's recognised as a queryset but i can't use data from it

Model

```
variation_category_choice = (
    ('color', 'color',),
    ('size', 'size',),
)

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variation_category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=variation_category_choice)
    variation_value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product
```

View

```
def product_detail(request, category_slug, product_slug):
    try:
        single_product = Product.objects.get(category__slug=category_slug, slug=product_slug)
        in_cart = CartItem.objects.filter(cart__cart_id=_cart_id(request), product=single_product).exists()
        variations = Variation.objects.filter(product=single_product)

    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    context = {
        'single_product': single_product,
        'in_cart': in_cart,
        'variations': variations
    }

    return render(request, 'store/product_detail.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<h1>{{variations.variation_value}}</h1>
```

Comment: For a given `single_product` you can have multiple `Variation`s. `.filter` returns quertyset. If you need a single `Variation` object you need to use `.get` instead. Or you need to iterate over filtered queryset.

Comment: I need all of them and display them. I used them as : variation_category : size/color so i need to display variation_value dinamicaly based on it but it's not displayed.. only the querysets not the values. so bassically i need to iterate over them